# Flutter appending fetched data to a listview inside a future builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-listview

I'd like to ask when using the `FutureBuilder` to display fetched data from a remote server in a `ListView`. I check if the bottom of the `ListView` was reached using `ScrollController`. Everything is working well until I try to load new data and append them to the existing `ListView` I fetch the data add them to my `Array` and the in `setState((){})` I update the list for the `FutureBuilder` this is obviously the wrong approach since then the whole `FutureBuilder` is rebuilt and so is the `ListView`. The changes however do appear all the new items are in the list as intended however it slows performance not significantly since `ListView` is not keeping tiles out of view active but it has a small impact on performance, but the main issue is that since `ListView` gets rebuilt, I'm thrown as a user to the start of this list that's because the `ListView` got rebuilt. Now what I would like to achieve is that the `ListView` doesn't get rebuilt every time I get new data. Here is the code of the whole `StateFulWidget`

```dart
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../widgets/rss_card.dart';
import '../extensions/colors.dart';
import '../extensions/rss.dart';
import '../main.dart';
import '../models/rss.dart';

class RssListView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? channel;

  const RssListView.fromChannel(this.channel, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RssListView> createState() => _RssListViewState();
}

class _RssListViewState extends State<RssListView>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  late RssListModel _rssListModel;
  double _offset = 0.0;
  final double _limit = 5.0;
  Future<List<RssItemModel>?>? _rssFuture;
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  Map<String, Object> _args({double? newOffset}) => {
        'offset': newOffset ?? _offset,
        'limit': _limit,
      };

  Future<bool> isConnected() async {
    var conn = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
    return (conn == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
            conn == ConnectivityResult.wifi ||
            conn == ConnectivityResult.ethernet)
        ? true
        : false;
  }

  Future<void> _pullRefresh() async {
    _rssListModel.refresh(_args(
      newOffset: 0,
    ));
    List<RssItemModel>? refreshedRssItems = await _rssListModel.fetchData();
    setState(() {
      _rssFuture = Future.value(refreshedRssItems);
    });
  }

  Future<List<RssItemModel>?> get initialize async {
    await _rssListModel.initializationDone;
    return _rssListModel.Items;
  }

  void _loadMore() async {
    List<RssItemModel>? moreItems = await _rssListModel
        .loadMoreWithArgs(_args(newOffset: _offset += _limit));
    setState(() {
      _rssFuture = Future.value(moreItems);
    });
  }

  void _showSnackBarWithDelay({int? milliseconds}) {
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds ?? 200),
      () {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(getDefaultSnackBar(
          message: 'No Internet Connection',
        ));
      },
    );
  }

  void _addScrollControllerListener() {
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          (_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent)) _loadMore();
    });
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _rssListModel = RssListModel.fromChannel(widget.channel, _args());

    isConnected().then((internet) {
      if (!internet) {
        _showSnackBarWithDelay();
      } else {
        _addScrollControllerListener();
        setState(() {
          _rssFuture = initialize;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 8,
        horizontal: 16,
      ),
      color: Colors.white,
      child: FutureBuilder<List<RssItemModel?>?>(
        future: _rssFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
            case ConnectionState.active:
              break;
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return getLoadingWidget();
            case ConnectionState.done:
              {
                if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty)
                  return _noDataView('No data to display');
                if (snapshot.hasError)
                  return _noDataView("There was an error while fetching data");

                return _refreshIndicator(snapshot);
              }
          }
          return _noDataView('Unable to fetch data from server');
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Returns a `RefreshIndicator` wrapping our `ListView`
  Widget _refreshIndicator(AsyncSnapshot snapshot) => RefreshIndicator(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
        triggerMode: RefreshIndicatorTriggerMode.anywhere,
        color: MyColors.Red,
        onRefresh: _pullRefresh,
        child: _listView(snapshot),
      );

  /// Returns a `ListView` builder from an `AsyncSnapshot`
  Widget _listView(AsyncSnapshot snapshot) => ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => RssCard(snapshot.data![index]),
      );

  /// Returns a `Widget` informing of "No Data Fetched"
  Widget _noDataView(String message) => Center(
        child: Text(
          message,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to hold onto the state in some `Listenable`, such as `ValueNotifier` and use `ValueListenableBuilder` to build your `ListView`. I  put together this demo to show you what I mean:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: const HomePage(),
  ));
}

@immutable
class Person {
  final String id;
  Person() : id = const Uuid().v4();
}

class DataController extends ValueNotifier<Iterable<Person>> {
  DataController() : super([]) {
    addMoreValues();
  }

  void addMoreValues() {
    value = value.followedBy(
      Iterable.generate(
        30,
        (_) => Person(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late final ScrollController _controller;
  final _generator = DataController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = ScrollController();
    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.position.atEdge && _controller.position.pixels != 0.0) {
        _generator.addMoreValues();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      body: ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: _generator,
        builder: (context, value, child) {
          final persons = value as Iterable<Person>;
          return ListView.builder(
            controller: _controller,
            itemCount: persons.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final person = persons.elementAt(index);
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(person.id),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly use a StreamBuilder for this? Or StreamBuilder doesn't hold on to a state?

Comment: Thank you very much, I took your idea and implemented it... had to rework it so it's async and it works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: Fantastic. I'm glad you figured it out 

Comment: your super.initState should be above the rest of the initState, not below'

Comment: @RandalSchwartz thank you so much for your input. I've corrected that mistake now.

Comment: Just remember it like "initState comes first, dispose comes last" and that will tell you where the super also comes within those.

Comment: Yes that just makes sense when I think about it. Thank you